# 'overflow evaluating the requirement' in Rust with Clone-like proc macros, wrapper structs and bounds to references

Tags: rust

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid the error generated by the [following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9065ee350d3f25a94a875e556896ca37), a struct implementing a trait using a proc-macro that evaluates the requirements like Clone or Deserialize (Lmao) with a trait bound on a reference (IntoIterator) in presence of a wrapper struct (Wrapper).

In my library I need to force every struct that implements a trait, Foo in this case, to implement `IntoIterator` too but in my codebase I have a wrapper struct implementing such trait that I cannot avoid.

```rust
use std::{marker::PhantomData, slice::Iter};

pub trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) -> &[u32];
}

pub struct Bar {
    x: Vec<u32>
}
impl Foo for Bar {
    fn foo(&self) -> &[u32] {
        &self.x
    }
}

impl<'it> IntoIterator for &'it Bar {
    type Item = &'it u32;
    type IntoIter = Iter<'it, u32>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.foo().iter()
    }
}

pub struct Wrapper<T: Foo> where  {
    t: T
}

impl<T: Foo> Foo for Wrapper<T> {
    fn foo(&self) -> &[u32] {
        self.t.foo()
    }
}

impl<'it, T: Foo> IntoIterator for &'it Wrapper<T>
where
    &'it T: IntoIterator<Item = &'it u32, IntoIter = Iter<'it, u32>>
{
    type Item = &'it u32;
    type IntoIter = Iter<'it, u32>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.foo().iter()
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Lmao<O>
where
    O: Foo,
    for<'it> &'it O: IntoIterator<Item = &'it u32>,
{
    phantom: PhantomData<O>
}

impl<O> Lmao<O>
where
    O: Foo,
    for<'it> &'it O: IntoIterator<Item = &'it u32>,
{
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            phantom: PhantomData
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `&_: IntoIterator`
  --> src/main.rs:47:10
   |
47 | #[derive(Clone)]
   |          ^
   |
   = help: consider increasing the recursion limit by adding a `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` attribute to your crate (`playground`)
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `&Wrapper<_>`
  --> src/main.rs:35:19
   |
35 | impl<'it, T: Foo> IntoIterator for &'it Wrapper<T>
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: 127 redundant requirements hidden
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `for<'it> IntoIterator` for `&'it Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<Wrapper<_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`
note: required by a bound in `Lmao`
  --> src/main.rs:51:22
   |
48 | pub struct Lmao<O>
   |            ---- required by a bound in this
...
51 |     for<'it> &'it O: IntoIterator<Item = &'it u32>,
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Lmao`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Clone` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0275`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: There is no reason to put such requirement on structure itself, you are creating this problem yourself

Comment: @Stargateur Maybe the OP does need it in the actual code; anyway, this is an interesting question. A Rust bug?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I don't believe it's a bug, just that `Clone` derive can't auto impl Clone with HRTB mixed with an generic and again HRTB don't make anysense here.

Comment: @Stargateur why HRTB don't make anysense? How do you express the IntoIterator requirement?

Comment: cause on your example there is no reason to put it on the structure definition, just put it on the impl or individual function impl

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `Clone` manually for `lmao` excactly like your `new` method (or just reuse `new`), since your struct does not contain any actual data which should be cloned.

```rust
impl<O> Clone for Lmao<O>
where
    O: Foo,
    for<'it> &'it O: IntoIterator<Item = &'it u32>,
{
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self {
            phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ofc an example and Clone is not the only one to not work, pyo3 and serde too